# Display file in binary format

Tags: vim, binary

I'd like to view executable file in Vim.

I used `:set binary` and thought that I will see only ones and zeros, but nothing changed.

How can I achieve to see only ones and zeros?

Comment: Uhh, binary in that sense actually means non-text. Btw, what would you do with all the "ones and zeros"?

Comment: I'm studying the process of translation of small assembly code with `as` utility in Linux and want to see the result as binary file.

Comment: @Idigas That's all.

Comment: Note: when you start wanting to use `xxd` to edit binary files, you will have problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086771/how-to-make-a-valid-input-for-xxd-r-in-vim-when-removing-a-byte

Comment: @xralf, Consider accepting the other answer as the solution.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Instead of ones and zeros, you can get an hexadecimal representation with:

```
:setlocal display=uhex
```

Also, you can get an hexadecimal dump of a buffer with:

```
:%!xxd
```

[Source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump)

Comment: This is useful but it won't display raw file (ones and zeros) as is stored on the harddrive. It's reformated with vim.

Comment: But they write it's not possible in `vim`. Maybe hex is more convenient for real work but it's strange that vim can't display raw file.

Comment: @xralf - The thing is, 1's and 0's "format" is not that really useful at all ... so there's not that much demand for it.

Comment: Hexadecimal and Binary conversion is straighforward. Hex mode is just that, hex digits. Studying binary data or raw data is a very specific matter, just for hacking, auditing, photography, cibersecurity... few tools can do that...

Comment: Instead of your answer, you could have given one for ones and zeros, because that's what had been asked for.

Comment: This is not an answer for the question

Comment: The first command didn't work for me, but the second one did.

Answer (score 52):

This did the trick for me:

```
:%!xxd -b
```